# gremlin console on Rexster (http://localhost:8182/doghouse/main/gremlin/graph) not working

Tags: gremlin, titan, rexster

I have installed titan-server-0.4.4 to use rexster to load titan graph.
Now that I can use `http://localhost:8182/doghouse/main/gremlin/graph` but don't know why the gremlin console is not working.
I might have been doing it wrong but don't know which part I'm doing wrong.

> Gremlin 2.4.0
>
> ```
>    \,,,/
>
>    (o o)
> ```
>
> -----oOOo-(_)-oOOo-----
>
> gremlin>graph = TinkerGraph.open()
>
> ==>javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.tg.TinkerGraph.open() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
>   Possible solutions: grep(), grep(java.lang.Object), e([Ljava.lang.Object;), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), use(java.util.List, groovy.lang.Closure), use(java.lang.Class, groovy.lang.Closure)
>
> gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
>
> ==>javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: TinkerFactory for class: Script5`

I tried with titan-1.0.0-hadoop1, and gremlin query worked fine, but had to change to server-0.4.4 to use rexster to display graph.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing and matching syntax/technology from TinkerPop 2.x with 3.x. Rexster is a TinkerPop 2.x based system. You are trying to then use TinkerPop 3.x based Titan 1.0 with Gremlin syntax like `TinkerFactory.createModern()` and `TinkerGraph.open()` that creates TinkerGraph databases as part of Titan. I would say:

1. Don't use anything TinkerPop 2.x at this point. That version has not been maintained for many years.
2. Do not use Titan - it is no longer maintained. Consider [JanusGraph](https://janusgraph.org/) (Titan's successor) or other [TinkerPop 3.x systems](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/#graph-systems).
3. If you are just getting started with graphs/TinkerPop, then simply start with TinkerGraph and Gremlin Console. Follow the [Getting Started Tutorial](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/getting-started/) and then read the [Gremlin Console Tutorial](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/). Finally, get familiar with the [Practical Gremlin](http://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html) book.